# sencha touch2 controller does not listening event

Tags: controller, sencha-touch

First, I do not speak English well . sorry..

my controller does not listening event.. between controller and view.

I use Ext.NavigationView

my view code : 
view.js

```
Ext.define('Mobile.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.data.Store'
],
config : {

    navigationBar : {
        items : [ {
            iconCls : 'list'
        },{
            iconCls : 'info',
            align: 'right'
        } ]
    },

    items : [{
        title:'test',
        //styleHtmlContent : true,
        scrollable : {
            direction : 'vertical',
            directionLock : true
        },
        items:[{
            html:'menu',
            itemId : 'main_menu',
            height: 300
        },{
            html:'notice',
            height: 30,
            style: 'background-color:green'
        },{
            xtype : 'list',
            height : 270,
            //styleHtmlContent:true,
            style: 'background-color:orange',
            store : Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: 'Mobile.model.Notice'
            }),

            loadingText : 'Loading...',
            itemTpl : [
                '<div style="overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; padding-right:12px;padding-top:4px;">',
                '<div style="font-family:Pictos; width:20px; font-size:1em; display:inline-block;">6</div>',
                '<div style="display:inline;">{title} [{created}]</div>',
                '</div>'
            ].join(''),

            scrollable : false
        },{
            html:'button',
            height: 80,
            style: 'background-color:navy'
        },{
            html:'Copyright',
            height: 30,
            style: 'background-color:olive'
        }]
    }]
}
```

view controller code:

```
Ext.define('Mobile.controller.MainController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
    refs: {
        main: 'main', //NavigationView
        menu : 'main #main_menu' // catch ok.
    },
    control: {
        //working
        'main': {
            initialize: function(obj, opt){
                //<debug>
                console.log('[controller.MainController] main view 초기화..');
                //</debug>
                obj.child('container list').getStore().load();
                console.log(this.getMenu()); // working
            }
        },
        //working
        'main button[iconCls=list]' : {
            tap: function(obj, evt, opt){
                //<debug>
                console.log('[controller.MainController] sitemap button tap..');
                //</debug>
            }
        },
        //working
        'main button[iconCls=info]' : {
            tap: function(obj, evt, opt){
                //<debug>
                console.log('[controller.MainController] login button tap..');
                //</debug>

                var datePicker = Ext.create('Ext.picker.Date');
                Ext.Viewport.add(datePicker);
                datePicker.show();

            }
        },
        //not wokring
        menu : {
            initialize : function(){
                console.log('test');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this event is not working ...

```
       //not wokring
        menu : {
            initialize : function(){
                console.log('test');
            }
        }
```

children component's event not working in controller.

by the way event is working in view. but not controller.

why..? thank you.

Comment: try this, add id to menu same as itemId.I mean "id : 'main_menu'".

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug related to itemId in control config: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?291456

You can try a workaround from the thread above or from this thread: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?293149